# QRCode which contains diffrent finder patterns

Tags: qr-code

I am using qr-encode library to generate Qrcode on unix platform. But i am not able to customization of generated Qrcode.
Can you please tell me using this library how to customize generated Qrcode.

i want to change finder patterns with different designs.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the manual of then **libqrencode** library:

http://www.linuxintheshell.org/2012/03/01/entry-001-qrencode/

Howewer, i'm not sure you can change the design of the qrcodes in the command line.

If you want to customize your qr-code with colors, shapes, ... online, you could use http://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/

Comment: Thanks for help but this link is not help me